# How to catch unhandled exception in WinCE?

Tags: c++, exception, windows-ce

In desktop Windows, I can use the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` function in `windows.h`, but it doesn't work in WinCE. How can I catch unhandled exceptions in WinCE?

Note: I am using C++ and not .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have found so far is to wrap the execution of every single thread in an application with:

```
__try
{
    // Call the thread start function here
}
__except(MyExceptionFilter(GetExceptionInformation())
{
    // Handle the exception here
}
```

This sounds like a lot of work, but is made relatively easy if you write a function that wraps the thread for you like this:

```
typedef struct {
    void* startFct;
    void* args;
} ThreadHookArgs;

// "params" contains an heap-allocated instance of ThreadHookArgs
// with the wrapped thread start function and its arguments.
DWORD WINAPI wrapThread(LPVOID params) {

    ThreadHookArgs threadParams;
    memcpy(&args, params, sizeof(ThreadHookArgs));

    // Delete the parameters, now we have a copy of them
    delete params;

    __try {
        // Execute the thread start function
        return ((LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) threadParams.startFct) (threadParams.args);
    }
    __except(MyExceptionFilter(GetExceptionInformation())
    {
        // Handle the exception here
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

}
```

Then write your own thread creation function that call the hook instead of the thread start function:

```
// Drop-in replacement for CreateThread(), executes the given
// start function in a SEH exception handler
HANDLE MyCreateThread( LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
                       DWORD dwStackSize,
                       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
                       LPVOID lpParameter,
                       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
                       LPDWORD lpThreadId)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThreadId;

    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE startFct = lpStartAddress;
    LPVOID startParam = lpParameter;

    // Allocate the hook function arguments on the heap.
    // The function will delete them when it runs.
    ThreadHookArgs* hookArgs = new ThreadHookArgs;
    hookArgs->fct = lpStartAddress;
    hookArgs->args = lpParameter;

    // Set the start function of the created thread to
    // our exception handler hook function
    startFct = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &wrapThread;
    startParam = hookArgs;

    // Start the hook function, which will in turn execute
    // the desired thread start function
    hThread = CreateThread( lpThreadAttributes,
                            dwStackSize,
                            startFct,
                            startParam,
                            dwCreationFlags,
                            &dwThreadId );

    return hThread;
}
```

Note that if you're using Windows CE 6 and newer, those versions have vectored exception handling, which might make it much easier:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488606%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

Comment: Vectored exception handling does NOT solve this issue, because vectored exception filters are called BEFORE any frame-specific filters are called, whereas unhandled exception filters are called AFTER all exceptions filters have been called. This is VERY error-prone as it invalidates many assumptions on which filter is called before the others.

Comment: Another problem with this solution. If you do not respect the Windows CE ABI entirely, then frame-based exception filters might get skipped as the kernel might not be able to unwind the stack correctly. Note that vectored exception filters are still called even when the program does not respect the Windows CE ABI.

Comment: Good points. As it were, I only use vectored exception handling to catch STATUS_CRASH_DUMP and bypass the error window one gets in such cases, dumping a log about the exception that triggered it instead; I also wasn't aware of ABI issues and the solution has been working pretty well so far. Sadly, there seems to be no true universal way to solve the issue.